# Игнорирование <probing privatePath=>

Tags: c#, xml

Проект скомпилирован в папку, включающую в себя .exe файл, .dll файл с идентичным названием, пара .json файлов (Все это в таком состоянии работает). При попытке переместить один из .dll файлов (был добавлен, как внешняя сборка) в некую папку (MyLibs) и при этом в "Название_проекта".exe.config были добавлены строки:

```
<configuration>
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
     <probing privatePath="MyLibs" /> 
  </assemblyBinding>
```

> Error:
> An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest ("Название проекта".deps.json) was not found:
> package: 'LibraryTest', version: '1.0.0'
> path: 'LibraryTest.dll'

Comment: `probing privatePath` - это элемент app.config приложения на классическом .NET Framework. У вас же, судя по .deps.json - приложение .NET Core.

Comment: [Default probing](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/dependency-loading/default-probing)